# How to overcome Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, tiles

I have two projects running on my Eclipse. I am able to run one of them, however if I try to run the second project then I get the error :

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
```

How to resolve this problem? I have re added the JAR files required for the execution and running of this program.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Struts2 replacement for tiles listener `org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener`.
To configure tiles without error, the `web.xml` should have an entry for listener. Open the `web.xml` from `WEB-INF` folder and add following code into it:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I have included this code. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Post a stacktrace, directory structure, libraries, configuration files all, anything else I forgot I will ask further.